# why doesn't haskell have heterogeneous lists

Tags: list, haskell, types, polymorphism, static-polymorphism

I don't understand why I can't construct a list that looks like `[1,"1",1.1]` in haskell. I don't think it's static typing that gets in the way because I thought that `head` would now have an ill defined type but then I thought about it and there is no reason the run-time system doesn't instantiate a different version of `head` whenever a list is fed into it so `head [1,"1",1.1]` would be typed as `List->Int` and `head (tail [1,"1",1.1])` would be typed as `List->String`. Since the run-time already does a lot of bookkeeping why doesn't it provide fancier polymorphic (or is it generic) versions of the various prelude functions? What am I missing here?

Comment: What type is the Nth element of `[1,"1",1.1]`?

Comment: @Gabe: give me a specific number and I'll unambiguously tell you what it is. Compile time or run-time.

Comment: @davidk01: tell me the type of the 4th element of a list _variable_... in other words a list which is an argument to a function? For that matter, tell me whether it even _has_ a 4th element, at compile time! If either the list or the index is a variable, you can't know the type at compile time.

Comment: davidk01: That's the problem -- the compiler doesn't know the specific number. If the compiler encounters `[1,"1",1.1] !! n` it can't tell what the type of the expression will be.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, obviously `[1,"1",1.1] !! n` is not typed. I can't tell what it's type is so how can the type system. `[1,"1",1.1] !! 1` on the other hand is an `Int`. You're still not answering the question.

Comment: davidk01: The fact that you can't tell me its type is the reason you can't construct such a list -- you answered your own question. If you know your list will always be an `Int`, a `String`, and a `Float` you have a tuple rather than a list.

Comment: @pelotom: `Exception`, since the list has length 3 and you are going past the length. Not sure how that's inconsistent with my question though. I typed `[1,2,3] !! 4` in ghci and it threw an exception. So the default behavior is to throw exception for indices that exceed the length.

Comment: @Gabe: No, `[1,2,3]` is typed as `[Int]` so `[1,2,3] !! 5` by your argument should be an `Int` because it type checks just fine but it is in fact an exception.

Comment: @davidk01: Actually, Gabe is entirely correct; exceptions are only visible from inside `IO` (the land of impure code), which is always the case if you're in GHCi.  *Nothing* was returned from `[1,2,3] !! 5`, which is acceptable: everything which *was* returned was an `Int`.

Comment: @Antal: Huh? Put it in a source file as `a = [1,2,3] !! 5` and tell me if the type checker raises any flags? It doesn't so Gabe's argument about the type being know at compile time is false. But if you do `f a` for some function `f` then you will most likely get an error because the type checker will compute the value of `a` and see that it raises an exception.

Comment: @davidk01: Of course the type checker doesn't raise any flags, because *everything* returned by `[1,2,3] !! 5` is an `Int`.  If that expression throws an exception, then *nothing* is returned—but a non-`Int` can never be returned.  (Sorry for the multiple negatives, it's a bit confusing.)  Exception-throwing is different from returning, which is why exceptions can only be caught within `IO`.  Since running a Haskell program is always done by running an `IO` action, you'll always see the result of the exception, but this doesn't violate type-safety.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Well if everything returned by `[1,2,3]` is an `Int`, which is not true if you put an out of bounds index, then it might as well be `[1,2,3] -> ??` since in out of bounds cases that is exactly how it acts. None of the examples I gave violate type safety either so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @davidk01: read carefully what @Antal S-Z said... exceptions are not returned values.

Comment: I believe that Antal is slightly incorrect. The error value (`_|_`) is included in *all* types, so an expression of any type can have that value. Of course the execution of your program ends whenever a value of `_|_` is encountered, so you can't ever detect it or do anything with it.

Comment: @Gabe: True, although I was trying to avoid getting into ⊥.  And GHC (not sure about the Haskell standard) does have real exceptions (which, admittedly, effectively return ⊥).  @davidk01: In the out-of-bounds case, *nothing is returned*.  This is fine.  What `[Int] -> Int` means is that *if* something is returned, *then* that thing will be an `Int`.  Requiring that something is always returned is equivalent to the halting problem and thus impossible.  And I never claimed that your examples (other than `[1,"1.1",1.1]`) violated type safety; what are you referring to?

Comment: Make the concept formal enough to be implemented.  Then try writing the types of all the standard Prelude and Data.List functions in your new formal notation.  In doing so, you will probably find out why it is not the norm: typed heterogeneous lists sound nice, but are a major pain to actually use, especially within the Haskell 98 type universe.

Comment: @mokus: Actually template haskell already has such features so what I'm asking for isn't as bad as you make it sound and I'll let you perform all the formal setup since I'm obviously too stupid to realize what's good for me.

Comment: @davidk01: You're not "too stupid to realize what's good for you", and I'm pretty sure that whatever you're trying to do is perfectly reasonable. However, I suspect you are misunderstanding some terminology--such as the true meaning of "static typing" and what that entails for run-time vs. compile-time knowledge--resulting in an awkward communication barrier. Types in Haskell are not simply like types in Javascript or Ruby except known ahead of time; the difference is deeper. I might be able to clarify things, but it would be lengthy and not really answer this question itself...

Comment: @camccann: How's it deeper? They are basically propositions about the program that another program verifies. I don't think it gets deeper than that.

Comment: @camccann: By the way I was being sarcastic. I should have done a general search on GADTs and other things before I posted the question since it appears a lot of my questions are addressed in various extensions of GHC.

Comment: There's no type information known at runtime.  All type information has to be known at compile time.  GHC has absolutely no way of determining a runtime type - it doesn't preserve any of that at runtime. There's (generally) no need.  Asking GHC for runtime type information would be like asking someone how they were constructed.  That information is long gone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is indeed the typing that prevents this. Consider the definition of a list (notice the type parameter `a`, which is missing from your types):

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

In the `Cons a (List a)` you can see that the type of thing at the head of the list must be the same type as the elements that follow it. To answer your question, you're not missing a lot: as you say the runtime could do it, but in Haskell you want to make these typing decisions at compile-time, not runtime.

If you want heterogeneous lists, you can see some wizardry by Oleg Kiselyov in his work on [HList](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/) (= Heterogeneous List). It may not be exactly what you want, but it's in the same rough direction.

Comment: And for the sake of clarity, HList's "heterogeneous lists" are really no different from right-nested 2-tuples. The interesting part isn't the lists themselves, it's the crazy type-level meta-programming deep magic Oleg uses to construct generic functions that work on arbitrary "lists".

Comment: @davidk01: the above is what you actually need to know.  At this point in your learning you don't need to know about HList or other type-hackery.  Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 3):

Because in Haskell all types are known at compile-time. There's no such thing as waiting until runtime to see what the type will be. And because this is sufficient to do anything you could want to do in a dynamically-typed system, while being easier to reason about to boot.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. In the examples I gave all the types are still know at runtime. If I give you a list `[1,"1.1",1.1]` and ask you to compute `head [1,"1.1",1.1]` then the result is unambiguously an `Int` whether you are at compile time or run-time.

Comment: @davidk01: it will be known at runtime, yes, but not at compile-time. It's easy to see what the type of the 2nd element of `[1, "1.1", 1.1]` is, because you're looking at a list literal, but what if you're trying to determine the nth element of an arbitrary list that is an argument to a function?

Comment: @Gabe: The type system already does a lot of computation when determining types. There is no reason it can't go the extra mile and type all the examples I gave at compile time.

Comment: @davidk01: assuming it could type your examples, what use would they be? You want the ability to get values at constant indices out of list constants? Then just write your constants like this: `idx1 = 1`, `idx2 = "1.1"`, etc. That's just as powerful as what you're describing.

Comment: @davidk01: If you want this, go to your favourite dynamic typed language.

Comment: @pelotom: It is not as powerful. I might have a statically typed function and some list that is specified somewhere else over which I don't have control but I have access to it at compile time and I know that all it's elements at compile time so indexing into it should give me specific elements with specific types which I can feed into my function in a statically safe manner.

Comment: @davidk01: And what would the type of `[1, "1.1", 1.1]` be?  You can't give it a sensible type other than something like `HCons Integer (HCons String (HCons Double HNil))`.  This works (the HList module supports such lists, and gives them types like that), but you can see why it's not the default.  Such lists are far less flexible than your standard `[a]`, and (IMHO) you'll usually want a tuple instead.

Comment: @davidk01: as @Gabe pointed out, you want a tuple, not a list... if a heterogeneous list can be of variable length then it is impossible to know the types of each of the elements at compile-time because you _don't even know how many elements it has_ at compile-time.

Comment: @davidk01: Here's a heterogeneous list with known length, you can use `fst` and `snd` instead of `head` and `tail` on it: `(1, ("1.1", (1.1, 'c')))`

Comment: @davidk01: I think it's actually possible to have heterogenous lists in a static programming language, but you may need dependent types.

Comment: @pelotom, davidk01: Good example with the tuples.  And now, with that in mind, someone try to tell me the type of `sort` on that kind of a list :)  Or even the type of `!!` or `take`.  Or even just the type of lists that happen to be homogeneous without known length.

Comment: @FUZxxl: see HList for a heterogenous typed list in Haskell.

Comment: Pointing a newcomer to HLists when they clearly haven't yet grasped the utility of homogeneous lists is a mistake in my view.

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, there actually is a package for heterogeneous lists, using non-trivial techniques and you really should make sure you understand the type system well before diving into this. You don't have this by default because of the type system. A list in Haskell isn't just a list. It's *a list of a's*, 'a' being Int, String, whatever you want. BUT, one list can contain only one type of values.

Note that you can define "heterogeneous lists" of elements satisfying some constraints using existential quantification, but I think you're not there yet and really should focus on understanding the other answers here before going any further.

Comment: +1 for the important point that Haskell lists are meant to be a *list of a's*.

Answer (score 3):

There is a heteregenous list type called HList (available on Hackage), but note that there probably is a type for the contents of your list.  Consider something like this:

```
history = [-12, "STATEMENT END", (-244, time January 4 2010), ...]
```

Your data has a type struggling to emerge, e.g.:

```
data HistoryEntry = Withdrawal Int | StatementClosing | ScheduledPayment Int CalendarTime

history = [Withdrawal 12, StatementClosing, ScheduledPayment 244 (time January 4 2010)]
```

In many cases, your data has a type that you just need to seek out.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Heterogenous collections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections)

```
{-# OPTIONS -fglasgow-exts #-}
--
-- An existential type encapsulating types that can be Shown
-- The interface to the type is held in the show method dictionary
--
-- Create your own typeclass for packing up other interfaces
--
data Showable = forall a . Show a => MkShowable a

--
-- And a nice existential builder
--
pack :: Show a => a -> Showable
pack = MkShowable

--
-- A heteoregenous list of Showable values
--
hlist :: [Showable]
hlist = [ pack 3
        , pack 'x'
        , pack pi
        , pack "string"
        , pack (Just ()) ]

--
-- The only thing we can do to Showable values is show them
--
main :: IO ()
main = print $ map f hlist
    where
        f (MkShowable a) = show a

{-

*Main> main
["3","'x'","3.141592653589793","\"string\"","Just ()"]

-}
```

Comment: This isn't HList, it's existential types.